# Can't ping when Mobile Hotspot is enable

Tags: windows-10, mobile-hotspot

In Windows 10, when Mobile Hotspot feature is enabled, my PC become unreachable in the network and can't even Ping on my IP.

Comment: Two ideas: AP isolation. Do you, in your hotspot settings, see anything that says "AP isolation" or "Multi AP"? If yes - Disable it. OR: You need to set a static arp routing. I'm not sure how to do that on windows but on android you can run the `arp -s <router-ip> <router-mac>` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Virtual Adapter` should not have Static IP!

When Mobile Hotspot is enabled, connected devices obtain IP in the different range of PC's range, Different range does not matter when Virtual Adapter's IP is DHCP, but when you set Static IP for `Virtual Adapter` it is important. PC's IP can't route in your network! so, nobody can ping your PC

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.

Answer (score 0):

Is our PC connected via a network cable or connected via a wireless router?

Generally, a PC connects to the Internet through a network cable, and then creates a hotspot to share with other devices. The problem you mentioned should not occur.

But if the PC connects to the wireless network through the wireless router to access the Internet, then the PC creates a hotspot for other devices. After creating the hotspot, the IP of the wireless network is changed to another fixed IP address by Windows. This IP address is the hotspot gateway. The address is automatically generated by the system.

For example:

If the gateway of the original router is 192.168.1.1, the IP address obtained after the wireless network card is connected to the wireless network is 192.168.1.2, and the external network is connected through the gateway 192.168.1.1.

Then, after creating the hotspot, Windows automatically changes the IP of the wireless network card. For example, the changed IP address is 192.168.131.1, and other devices connected to the shared hotspot will be assigned these IP addresses: 192.168.131.** (** Indicates 2, 3, 4...), they connect to the external network through 192.168.131.1.

So according to the above example, 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.131.1 are not directly communicable.

Therefore, if the PC accesses the Internet through the wireless network connection of the router and opens the wireless hotspot to share with other devices, the PC cannot access the network itself, nor can it ping its own IP, and other devices cannot connect to the hotspot.

Maybe there is a third-party software that can fulfill this kind of demand, and Windows does not work on its own.